# Add a link to a site developed using photoshop

Tags: php, html, web-deployment

Is it possible to add a link to a site that had its template developed with Photoshop?

I know back in the day you would develop the template in Photoshop and then use a tool like Dreamweaver to add the links. I didn't think it was possible to add it through PHP dynamically.

Am I correct in this or have things changed? I ask because I have recently began a web development job and told my boss he could not add a link dynamically using PHP because his template was already designed in Photoshop.

Please help me clarify.

PS. I'm pretty sure some of you may down vote me or whatever but I am seriously inquiring.

Comment: Photoshop generates image files. Websites are, for the most part, HTML, not images.

Comment: @MattBall But it might explain why one of my work PCs used to always insist on opening CSS files with Photoshop :P

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible. 
I don't know what do you mean by template developed in Photoshop. Do you have an actual HTML code, or just use some cut of images? Using just images is really a bad idea. Site will take longer to load, users won't be able to copy text from your site, neither search engines would. And editing becomes a pain. But even in this case you can add links to an image, just using `position:absolute;` for them.

But normally what you want to do is take a Photoshop file, cut the necessary images and use them for manually writing HTML and CSS. This is how many of the sites are created nowadays.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I meant that he created a template in photoshop with the words of the link already pre-rendered in the image. I was asking if it was possible to add a link to those pre-rendered links programmatically?

Comment: yes, use area tag http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp or just add a regular link and position it on top of the link on the picture, while making it transparent (harder way)